# Hitting max character length for AWS Eventbridge json payload

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, payload, aws-event-bridge

I have a big json payload of around 12K characters. AWS Eventbridge is not letting me create event as there is a payload limit of 8192 characters.
How would I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [API doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_Target.html), this is a hard limit on the API level. A workaround would be to split it into two targets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mean create some filters to reduce json length and route it to 2 targets?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to handle larger payloads on Eventbridge would be to put the payload to S3 and pass a reference (bucket name + key) as the payload.